# Android Studio TCP Client

Tags: android-studio, tcpclient

I´m trying do build a tcp client on android studio, i copied this code but this error happened. Can someone help me to solve this error?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Write the code and output here instead of putting links.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you are using this package `java.util.logging.Handler` instead of this one `android.os.Handler`.